# Help changing coordinates back after partitioning an image?

Tags: image-processing, coordinate-transformation

I'm new to *Mathematica*. I was just wondering how I could change the coordinates back after I partitioned an image. For example, if I used `ImagePartition[]` to split an image into 8 equal pieces and found a point on each image, how would I change the coordinates of those points back (i.e. if I plotted those coordinates it would appear in the proper place on each image)?

Here's the image I'm using:
[image: frog]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwlup.jpg"];
imgParts = ImagePartition[img, {100, 87}];
imgPartsKeypoints = Map[ImageKeypoints, imgParts,{2}]
```

I was wondering how to convert the coordinates of the keypoints into coordinates that could be plotted on the original image.

Comment: Can you at least give the example image ou have, so that we can conduct tests on it?

Comment: Sorry! It was this one (a random image): http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/frog-1.jpg    I was just experimenting with ImagePartition and ImageKeypoints. I'll edit the original post to clarify.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I think SE prefers images to be uploaded to its own imgur account (e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwlup.jpg).  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.  Maybe others will comment (or upvote this comment).

Comment: `ImageAssemble[
 MapIndexed[
  Show[#, Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Red, 
      Point[imgPartsKeypoints[[## & @@ #2]]]}]] &, imgParts, {2}]]`?

Comment: @kglr I think the OP want that coordinate value

Comment: maybe `translatedKeypoints = 
  MapIndexed[
   TranslationTransform[{(#2[[1]] - 1) 100, (#2[[2]] - 1) 87}]@# &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose[imgPartsKeypoints], {2}];`?